# не получается создать переменную в массиве js

Tags: javascript, массивы, ajax, gulp

У меня есть маленький проект, который я решил перенести на gulp, чтобы было поудобнее. Захотел разделить весь js по файлам, а то путаюсь и глаза разбегаются, но почему-то, с такой, вроде, прекрасной идеей, вышла проблема, что мне выдаёт ошибку там, где её не было. Есть форма, при сабмите которой, нужно пробежаться, проверить данные и закинуть на бекенд. Я помещаю все инпуты в массив inputElements:

```
let inputElements = [
  formSurname = addForm.userSurname,
  formName = addForm.userName,
  formLastName = addForm.userLastName
];
```

Это выдаёт мне:

> script.js:107 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: formSurname is not defined

Я отлаживал консоль логом — значение есть. Решил перед массивом сделать объявление переменных и потом просто положить их в этот массив, — так работает, но выходит уже 8 строчек, что не очень классно...

У меня есть два скрипта: старый (там где всё кучкой) и новый, куда я всё добавляю import`ами, и не работает именно в новом. Все переменные находятся в отдельном файле, которые нужны — импортирую. Я подумал, что может тогда просто объявить addForm в этом же файле, но так тоже не работает.

ps: я только изучаю js, поэтому может я вообще туплю нереально, но честно не понимаю, что не так :(

Comment: а почему вы решили, что это массив? И в каком учебники вы видели, чтобы "массивы" вот именно так задавались?

Comment: @ArchDemon, и что это тогда, если не массив?

Comment: @ArchDemon, вроде как, под массив попадает очень даже: https://learn.javascript.ru/array

Comment: т.е. конструкцию `[formSurname = addForm.userSurname]` вы считаете один в один с `[addForm.userSurname]` ? Да и в вашем случае стоит создавать не массив, а объект. С ним проще работать

Comment: @ArchDemon, нет, не считаю, мой вариант сохраняет значение: **addForm.userSurname** в **formSurname**, а запись [addForm.userSurname] — просто значение, на которое не получится сослаться, по индексу только

Comment: и зачем мне создавать целый объект? мне нужно просто пройтись циклом и забыть про этот массив зачем нужно усложнять созданием объекта

Comment: `inputElements.formSurname` выглядит нагляднее, чем `inputElements[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let inputElements = [
   addForm.userSurname,
   addForm.userName,
   addForm.userLastName
];

let [formSurname, formName, formLastName] = inputElements;
```

Comment: ну, в целом да, прикольно и работает, но почему мой вариант перестал работать? может, мне бы ответ на этот вопрос помог бы познать какую-то истину js

Comment: Так устроен JavaScript, рекомендую лучше вникнуть в его синтаксис и вам будет проще с ним работать

Comment: как раз этим и занимаюсь) спасибо Вам за помощь!

Comment: Рад был помочь)))